# Can I dim the rest of the page on hover with only CSS?

Tags: css

I'm not very good at explaining, but hopefully I can get my point across with some nifty photoshop.

Currently, when you hover links on my page, it looks like this:

http://i.gyazo.com/086a81e116c55b2660689e3807b201ca.gif

But I want it to dim the whole page on hover besides the link, sort of like:

http://i.gyazo.com/f6523ae998ad826e6ad338c055f5ae3c.gif

Below is the code for the links, and I'm pretty sure there's next to nothing I'm doing *right*, but maybe it'll help. (I'm hardly past "beginner" in the world of coding. I can usually get my way around CSS, but this stumps me.)

```
.linkage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 18px;
    z-index:999;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: arial;
}

.linkage a {
    color: #fcfcfc;
}

.linkage a:hover+.dim{
        color: #fff;
        font-size:30px;
    text-shadow: -2px 2px 8px #fff, 1px -1px 8px #fff;
}

.dim {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -6;
    display: none;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: you could use a snippet code to help us

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing, this is what are you looking for.

```css
body {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
.links  {
  height: 3em;
}


.link {
  transition: font-size 500ms ease 0s;
  color: #666;
}
.link:hover { 
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

/* relevant part */
.link:active {
  z-index: 5;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
/* adding pseudo element to "dim" the page on click */
.link:active::after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
  <div class="links">
  <a href="#" class="link">Lorem ipsum.</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">Ipsam, placeat!</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">Dicta, aliquam?</a>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum sequi, vitae, numquam earum molestiae illo, sapiente delectus enim possimus quod incidunt hic ab neque eaque provident, consequatur sint. Nihil neque natus amet eaque dolorum accusantium voluptatem aspernatur! Voluptas pariatur qui possimus incidunt beatae in atque nobis nostrum, vero tempora porro, ipsum, adipisci. Quasi fugit amet facilis, aliquid dolores ab molestiae dolorem obcaecati quo, perferendis ullam quas harum iste! Aperiam sunt quis cumque culpa esse mollitia nam autem animi dolorum sequi, similique delectus laboriosam tenetur vel saepe. Ut enim facilis quia, iusto neque dolores. Similique dolores corporis totam nesciunt et tempora.</p>
```